# Operator >> doesn't like vector<bool>?

Tags: c++, file, vector, boolean, ifstream

I have the following code which basically takes a vector and writes it to a file, and then opens the file and writes the content into a different vector.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<bool> q, p;
//         ^^^^
    q.resize(5, 0);
    q[0] = 1;
    q[2] = 1;
    q[4] = 1;

    ofstream ofile("file.log");

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        ofile <<q[i]<<" ";

    ofile.close();

    ifstream ifile("file.log");

    p.resize(5);

    int i = 0;
//        vvvvvvvvvvvv
    while(ifile>> p[i])
    {
        cout <<i<<"\t"<<p[i]<<endl;
        i++;
    }

    ifile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

What I noticed is that this code compiles and runs with no problem when the vector contains double, int, and long data types, but produces an error if it is changed to bool. This is the error message that I get:

```
../src/timeexample.cpp:31: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘ifile >> p.std::vector<bool, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Alloc = std::allocator<bool>](((long unsigned int)i))’
```

So, does anyone know why this happens?

Thank you

Comment: There's no `vector<bool>` in the code you posted.

Comment: I believe a bool variable has a size of 1 bit. so a bitshift would do nothing. Check @Chris I was wrong read the specification as bit when it clearly says byte.

Comment: @Nomad101, Variables have to be at least one byte.

Comment: @chris you are totally right. I read the specification wrong thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: There is vector<double>. I change double to different types. It could be bool. I just fix it to show bool.

Comment: @Nomad101: `bool`s are one byte, since the spec says nothing can be smaller than that (pedantically, that nothing smaller can be addressed). Infamously taking advantage of that is `vector<bool>`, which does use one bit for each bool, allocated in byte-size chunks. It's a Very Bad Thing, by virtue of being surprising behavior in a `std` container, and occasionally causes frustration.

Comment: @peachykeen so `bool` values are indeed 1 bit within a `vector<bool>` interesting. Was i correct in thinking bit shifting a 1 bit value is impossible, or more useless as it would just end up being the same value?

Comment: @peachykeen, Technically, one or more, though I believe most implementations use one byte.

Comment: @Nomad101, If there was a 1-bit type, shifting that by any number of places other than 0 would result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @chris I thought that since it was just 1 bit it would stay the same although thinking about it more that makes total sense seeing as the result would technically be nothing. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Nomad101: For storage purposes, yes. Most implementations do that by bitshifting and packing; the first 8 bits are shifted by their position and go into one byte, the next 8 are shifted by `pos % 8` and go into byte 2, and so on. It's a good idea, for efficiency, but isn't widely known and worse yet, behaves differently than all the other `vector` types. In fact, `vector<bool>` is a great example of how *not* to use template specialization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is specialized to have space efficiency. `operator[]` wouldn't be able to return an addressable variable, so it returns a [`std::vector<bool>::reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference) proxy object instead. Just input it to a temporary variable and transfer it:

```
bool b;
while (ifile >> b) {
    p[i] = b;
    cout <<i<<"\t"<<b<<endl;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`vector<bool>` is not what you think. It is a specialization of std::vector that is optimized for space and not for operations on elements, trying to reduce the `bool` storage by using bits to represent `bool` values. When bits are used the stream operators cannot work anymore.

Se [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/) for the important results of the optimization:

> - The storage is not necessarily an array of bool values, but the library implementation may optimize storage so that each value is
>     stored in a single bit.
> - Elements are not constructed using the allocator object, but their value is directly set on the proper bit in the internal storage.
> - Member function flip and a new signature for member swap.
> - A special member type, reference, a class that accesses individual bits in the container's internal storage with an interface that
>     emulates a bool reference. Conversely, member type const_reference is
>     a plain bool.
> - The pointer and iterator types used by the container are not necessarily neither pointers nor conforming iterators, although they
>     shall simulate most of their expected behavior.

There is another data structure that you can use int this way, if you know how many `bool` values you have at compile time : [bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

It has stream operators defined, which is what you are aiming at.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It definitely had something for me to learn.